# Tar up all PDFs in a directory, retaining directory structure

Tags: find, tar, recursive

I'm trying to create a compressed tarball that contains all PDF files that exist in one of my directories. The directory structure needs to be retained. Empty directories are not needed, but I really don't care if they're there.

For example, say I had a directory that looked like this:

```
dir
dir/subdir1
dir/subdir1/subsubdir1/song.mp3
dir/subdir2
dir/subdir2/subsubdir1
dir/subdir2/subsubdir1/document.pdf
dir/subdir2/subsubdir1/another-song.mp3
dir/subdir2/subsubdir1/top-ten-movies.txt
dir/subdir3
dir/subdir3/another-document.pdf
```

After running the command, I'd like to have `dir.tar.gz` contain this:

```
dir
dir/subdir2
dir/subdir2/subsubdir1
dir/subdir2/subsubdir1/document.pdf
dir/subdir3
dir/subdir3/another-document.pdf
```

Possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will list all the PDFs:

```
$ find dir/ -name '*.pdf'
./dir/subdir2/subsubdir1/document.pdf
./dir/subdir3/another-document.pdf
```

You can pipe that to `xargs` to get it as a single space-delimited line, and feed that to `tar` to create the archive:

```
$ find dir/ -name '*.pdf' | xargs tar czf dir.tar.gz
```

<sub>(This way omits the empty directories)</sub>

Comment: That's so awesome, thanks for the help. Here's what I came up with: `find docs \( -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.mp3' \) -printf '"%p"\n' | xargs tar czf docs-media.tar.gz`

Comment: @mattalexx: Beware that this command will not work if any of the file names contain spaces or `\'"` (xargs's fault), and will not work if there are too many file names (the kernel's fault).

Comment: @Gilles Regarding filenames with spaces and single quotes, the `-printf '"%p"\n'` part takes care of that (at least it did for me).

Comment: @Gilles Interesting about the kernel restriction. How many arguments can you have in a command in Linux?

Comment: @mattalexx: It's not the number of arguments, but their total length (including one terminating null byte per argument). Under Linux, the limit is 131072.

Comment: Oh, on the “will not work”, note that the failure mode here is that if the command line is too long, xargs will split it up, so that **the last tar invocation will silently overwrite files written by previous invocations**.

Comment: That failure can be avoided with `tar r` (as opposed to `tar c`).  However, it's not compatible with `tar z`, so you'll have to do the compression once at the end.

Comment: @ephemient That's what [Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/tar-up-all-pdfs-in-a-directory-retaining-directory-structure/5650#5650) does

Comment: Gah, I fail at reading.  And here I was thinking of suggesting using `cpio` too, when `pax` is already in Gilles' answer…

Answer (score 6):

With bash ≥4 or zsh and GNU tar:

```
tar -czf dir.tar.gz dir/**/*.pdf
```

This might not work if you have a very large number of PDF files and the command line is too long. Then you would need a more complex find-based solution (again, using GNU tar):

```
tar -cf dir.tar -T /dev/null
find dir -name '*.pdf' -exec tar -rf dir.tar {} +
gzip dir.tar
```

Alternatively (and portably) you can create the archive with [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html).

```
pax -w -x ustar -s '/\.pdf$/&/' -s '/.*//' . | gzip >dir.tar.gz
```

The first `-s` says to include all `.pdf` files, without changing their name. The second `-s` says to rename all other files to an empty name, which actually means not to include them in the archive.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to mention zsh's `**`; I didn't even realize bash 4 had that now