# How store in a variable a file list that includes the backslash when needed?

Tags: find, backup, filenames, tar

**Main question:**

I am writing a script to perform a backup. I make a list of files in the following way:

```
LISTOFFILES=$(find ~ \( -name '*.[pP][dD][fF]' -o -name '*.[oO][dD][tT]' \))
```

The variable `LISTOFFILES` stores more or less something like:

```
/home/user/file1.pdf /home/user/file2.odt /home/user/Python Tutorial.pdf
```

My next step is:

```
tar cvf backup.tar $LISTOFFILES
```

Bash response is:

```
/home/user/file1.pdf
/home/user/file2.odt
/home/user/Python: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Tutorial.pdf
```

I understand that Bash assumes that `Python` and `Tutorial.pdf` are different files.

Is there a way to do a list of files with backslash included with `find` or should I change to use `ls` with pipes?

I'd like read your tips and advices.

**My other question:**

*The answer to this question is not really important, but one tip could help*

How to list files only with the file name without the file path?

For example: `file` instead of `/home/user/file`.

I've trying with `find` command with `prune` and `path` options, but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for your main question, you'll need to take a different approach. Your method is putting all of the files into a single string in $LISTOFFILES. Then when you go to access it, you're not using quotes which causes it to split on spaces and give you the result you're seeing.

The simplest way to get the result you want is the following:

```
find ~ \( -name '*.[pP][dD][fF]' -o -name '*.[oO][dD][tT]' \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf backup.tar
```

What we did there was to run find, and separate each result with a NULL char (the -print0 part). The output of find is then piped to xargs which reads in a list of files separated by the NULL char (the -0 argument tells xargs to do this), and pass that list of files as arguments to 'tar'.

For your second question:
If you want to get just filenames only from the `find` command, use printf

```
find /path/to -printf '%f\n'
file.txt
```

If you mean in general, not just with find,
 it's easiest to use `basename`.

```
# basename /path/to/file.txt
file.txt
```

basename is designed to do exactly that, and nothing else.

Comment: ...or, if you don't want to spawn a new process with `basename` you could use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).

Comment: Yes, was going for simple over efficient :-). There are also issues with that first command like when you get to large number of files as you can exceed the max number of arguments (in addition to spawning an extra proc for xargs). Can do a while read loop, but much more complex.

Answer (score 3):

### Why your attempt failed and how to fix it

You can accumulate a list of file names returned by `find`, but only if there are no newlines in file names, and you need to take precautions.

When you write an unquoted command substitution or variable expansion, like `$LISTOFFILES` here, the shell performs [word splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) and [globbing (wildcard expansion)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_06) on the result.

Rule: always put double quotes around command substitutions and variable expansions.
Exception: if you understand why you need to leave off the double quotes, and why it's safe to do so.

Here, you need to leave off the double quotes, because word splitting is what splits the string into newline-separated bits. But by default it also splits at other whitespace characters. So you need to make that safe, and turn off globbing as well. You accomplish the former by setting the [`IFS` variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) to a single newline and the latter by invoking [`set -f`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html).

```
IFS='
'
set -f
tar cvf backup.tar $LISTOFFILES
```

Note that there are no backslashes involved. Backslashes are used when you input filenames directly, not when they're produced by commands like `find`.

### The usual way to use `find`

Rather than parse the output of `find`, you should make it invoke the command you want to run on the files, through the `-exec` action. This takes care of the case where there are so many files that the maximum command line length is exceeded: the program is invoked as many timed as necessary.

Here, this is a little difficult because you can't invoke `tar -c` multiple times (it would start over from a new empty archive at each invocation). But see [Tar up all PDFs in a directory, retaining directory structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/tar-up-all-pdfs-in-a-directory-retaining-directory-structure/5650#5650)

### Easier methods

If there aren't too many files, and you're running ksh93 or bash ≥4 or zsh, then use the `**` wildcard to recurse into subdirectories. You need to set some shell options first:

```
set -o globstar                  # on ksh93
shopt -s globstar -s extglob     # on bash 4
setopt ksh_glob                  # on zsh
tar cvf backup.tar ~/**/*.@(PDF|pdf|ODT|odt)
```

In zsh, with no particular settings, you can write that pattern as `~/**/*.(PDF|pdf|ODT|odt)`. After `setopt extglob`, you can write it as `~/**/(#i)*.(pdf|odt)`.

Or you can use [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html):

```
pax -w -x ustar -s '/\.pdf$/&/' -s '/\.PDF$/&/' -s '/\.odt$/&/' -s '/\.ODT$/&/' -s '/.*//' ~ >backup.tar
```

### If you don't want the path prefix

There are ways with `tar` and `pax`, but the simplest approach is to change to the directory you want to archive first.

```
( IFS='
'; set -f; cd ~ && tar cvf /path/to/backup.tar $(find . …) )
( cd ~ && pax -w … . ) >backup.tar
```

Answer (score 2):

### First question:

The answer to your first question is **`quotes`**.

Instead of doing -> `tar cvf backup.tar $LISTOFFILES`

Do this          -> `tar cvf backup.tar "$LISTOFFILES"`

Let's take a look at an example (I took one of your file for this demo, even though the file does not exist on my computer, look at the error's I am getting with and without quotes) -

```
[jaypal:~] file="/home/user/Python Tutorial.pdf"

[jaypal:~] ls $file
ls: /home/user/Python: No such file or directory
ls: Tutorial.pdf: No such file or directory
```

Error appeared for two files `/home/user/Python` and `Tutorial.pdf`. Let's put a `quote` to our `variable` and see what we get.

```
[jaypal:~] ls "$file"
ls: /home/user/Python Tutorial.pdf: No such file or directory
```

Error appeared only once for file `/home/user/Python Tutorial.pdf`

### Second question:

To prune the `/path/to/file` there are several ways. My favourite would be `awk` but I'll show you one for `sed` too.

**`sed` method:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "$filename"
/home/user/file1.pdf /home/user/file2.odt /home/user/Python Tutorial.pdf

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "$filename" | sed 's@/home/user/@@g'
file1.pdf file2.odt Python Tutorial.pdf
```

You can include it in your script like this -

```
LISTOFFILES=$(find ~ \( -name '*.[pP][dD][fF]' -o -name '*.[oO][dD][tT]' \) | sed 's@/home/user/@@g' )
```

Thing to remember here is we are doing `substitution`. We are substituting `/home/user/` to `nothing`. If you are `find`ing files from more than one directories then you can either make
tons and tons of substitutions (yikes!) or do the `awk` way.

**`awk` method:**

```
awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
```

Yep, thats it. Would work for files you `find` under any directory or their sub-directories.

So your script could have this in the following way -

```
LISTOFFILES=$(find ~ \( -name '*.[pP][dD][fF]' -o -name '*.[oO][dD][tT]' \) | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
```

### Other Tips and Tricks:

Here are some random tips that I think may be useful to you -

#### To `find` file names `insensitively`, use `iname` instead of what you have right now.  Check this out -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -name "j*.txt"
./jP.txt

[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -iname "j*.txt"
./jj.TXT
./jP.txt
```

#### Other ways of pruning the `/path/to/file` is by using `basename`. I will give an example and you can incorporate it in your script as you feel comfortable.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] filename="/usr/bin/java.pdf"

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "$filename"
/usr/bin/java.pdf

[jaypal:~/Temp] basename "$filename"
java.pdf
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your quote solution wont work because all the files will be joined together as a single argument. The only way to do that with shell variables would be to use an array which cant work (reliably) with the approach originally used.

Comment: I tried on my computer. Worked ok. `[jaypal:~/Temp] file=$(find . -name "*p*" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
[jaypal:~/Temp] for i in "$file"; do echo "$i"; done
backup
split.pl
XDR_Split.pl
gtpparser.sh` all files appear on new lines.

Comment: They appeared on separate lines because `find` printed them out on separate lines. Change your echo to `echo "<$i>"` and watch it fail spectacularly :-)

Comment: Thanks @Jaypal I'll play with <code>awk</code> and <code>sed</code> when I'll have time. About the <code>iname</code> option, I am writing a script that should work in Solaris and Linux, <code>iname</code> is not available in Solaris.