# 'Tar' the result of a 'find', preserving the directory structure

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, pipe, tar

I want to **[tar](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar)** all the ****.txt*** files that I get as the result of a **[find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)** command, that exist in a directory having a tree structure like this:

- **Directory_name**
- - **dir1**
- - - file1.pdf
- - - file1.txt
- - **dir2**
- - - file2.pdf
- - - file2.txt
- - **dir3**
- - - file3.pdf
- - - file3.txt

(the filenames are just examples).

But I want to **preserve the directory structure**.

What command can give me a *tar.gz* file with this content?

- **dir1**
- - file1.txt
- **dir2**
- - file2.txt
- **dir3**
- - file3.txt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to feed the output of a command as arguments to another:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcvf the_tarball.tar.gz
```

Note here the `-print0` from find and `-0` from xargs work in conjunction to delimit file names correctly (so that names with spaces and such aren't a problem).

Comment: xargs is not even necessary, you can pipe the output of find directly to tar via stdin. For your example:
```find . -iname '*.txt' | tar zcvf the_tarball.tar.gz --files-from -```
Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9534272/4017010 and the general topic was already discussed here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/tar-up-all-pdfs-in-a-directory-retaining-directory-structure

Comment: Hi, this worked perfectly. And thanks doktor5000 for the precision :)